# Is it possible to run a proxy server on "OpenShift Online" or appfog? If yes, how?

Tags: proxy, haproxy, openshift-online-2

In the [openshift documentation](http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_system_architecture_guide.html) it says under 4.2:

> In OpenShift Online, proxy ports are not directly accessible from outside the collection of nodes.

To explain the question:

We have a tiny proxy server script running on such a free openshift gear. The script is tested and working when running on an Ubuntu server and when a user sets his LAN proxy settings to the right port and right ip, then he can surf the internet through that proxy.

We also asked a code oriented question about this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896499/how-do-you-get-this-node-js-proxy-server-to-work-on-a-host-like-openshift-or-app).

The question:

Is it possible to run such a proxy server on "OpenShift Online" and to surf the internet using it. 
And if yes, what has to be done, to make the connection between proxy server and browser?
(When you are more familiar with appfog, that's fine)

Comment: No, you can't do this. Besides the obvious technical reasons, it's too prone to abuse.